# Html direction attribute is not working

Tags: html, right-to-left

In my webpage I set the locale to arabic and want to change the direction of the content display from right to left by using `<html dir = "rtl">`. But it is not displaying all the divisions of webpage from right to left some are getting reflected and some are not.

Is there any suggestion to change all the content display from right to left of a web page?

Comment: You set the rtl for the text, you need to change your floats and margins for it to work.

Comment: Also, can you post some example codes / examples?

Comment: The attribute sets specific features such as layout direction of tables and the basic writing direction of text. It does not magically change things if you e.g. place some element to the left with CSS positioning. Please post a code example that demonstrates what you mean and specify what is the problem (expected/desired rendering vs. actual rendering).

Answer (score 35):

This is old question, but i hope it'll help someone,
If `direction:rtl;` didn't work then try to override bidi in your css

```
unicode-bidi: bidi-override !important;
direction: unset !important;
text-align:right;
```

Comment: Thanks, The `unicode-bidi` property solved my problem

Comment: `unicode-bidi: bidi-override !important;` will mess up your numbers it seems. 10:16:56 becomes 65:61:01 which is nonsense of course or easier 2022 will become 2202.

Answer (score 4):

The following code

```
body {
   direction: rtl;
}
```

will work like sugar.

Answer (score 3):

`HTML dir="rtl"` or `CSS direction:rtl` is to control BiDi for the language script.

But in most cases where mixing different scripts you need to add also `HTML align="right"` or `CSS text-align:right` which is used to control visual display alignment.

Comment: Is this fine?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50597254/can-i-use-below-code-html-css-to-make-my-website-compatible-with-rtl

Answer (score 1):

Jsut use this style:

```
direction: ltr; 
unicode-bidi: embed;
```

Answer (score 0):

[You can use CSS instead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction):

```css
* {
  direction: rtl;
}
```

You can use * selector: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_all.php *(See 'More Examples')*

Comment: I want that the direction rtl has to work for all elements in the page block level or non block level.

Answer (score 0):

in my case it was input type text and the value was url appearing like

"/https://test.com" instead of  "https://test.com/"
even [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20798667/why-is-a-trailing-punctuation-mark-rendered-at-the-start-with-directionrtl/20799360#20799360) didn't help

after trying for a while finally following solution worked for me

```
.align-right-dir-ltr {
    text-align: right;
    direction: ltr;
}
```

note : in my html is the dir = "rtl"

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue on an HTML input. This CSS solution worked in Chrome.

```
    .rtl {
        direction: rtl;
        unicode-bidi: bidi-override !important;
    }
```