# Formatting a PHP multi line string

Tags: php, wordpress, email, contact-form-7

I have been trying to create a contact form auto-responder with a select list, one of the main sources I used is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40129714/1759249)

The only change I did to his code is obviously the variables and changed

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_mail_sent', 'contact_form_autoresponders' );
```

to

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_mail_sent', array($this, 'contact_form_autoresponders' ), 5);
```

I have been trying to create an automated email responder for any options out of the selected 'select' menu.

I have been importing another file.php which contains all the string variables I need with "<<

all the variables in file.php looks like this:

```
$some_variable =<<<EOT multiple 
                    lines 
                     here
 EOT;
```

Since My email responses are in Hebrew I want the responded mail to be sent right to left and I am looking all over the place for a way to align my string to the right and add some URL marks and can't find it.

I tried adding this to the Headers and String head and it didn't work out for me

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en" 
direction="rtl">
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: if you are asking in context of mail message, try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20680966/2962442

Comment: in your modification, you replace the second argument being passed which is a `STRING` with an `ARRAY`. Is the add_action function prepared to deal with that?

Comment: @kmlnvm 
I'm asking in the context of a String that needs to be translated into an e-mail

Comment: @Yonihodeffi it depends on your IDE I think, e.g.: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-text-direction.html
But remember when you send email to change direction of text in html or css.

Comment: @Yonihodeffi I don't know if rtl will work with english

Comment: @kmlnvm I tried using HTML and it didn't work, I am writing a question here after many many different tries. 
It's like the mail server completely ignore the fact I am sending him HTML.

I know it's plain text by default but I already changed wp_mail to support HTML.

Comment: @Yonihodeffi please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Replace...

`direction="rtl"`

with

`dir="rtl"`

You can find more informations here https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-dir

Remember to change lang attribute too.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, if your **`file.php`** included an **array of posted object properties** (i.e. `$this->option1`, `$this->option2`) then the code, based on the link you gave, would look something like:

```
#our autoresponders function
function contact_form_autoresponders( $contact_form ) {

    if( $contact_form->id==1234 ){ #your contact form ID - you can find this in contact form 7 settings

        #retrieve the details of the form/post
        $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
        $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();                          

        $msg = array();
        #set autoresponders based on dropdown choice, in an array     
        switch( $this->posteddata){ #your dropdown menu field name
            case 'California':
            $msg+="California email body goes here";
            break;

            case 'Texas':
            $msg+="Texas email body goes here";
            break;

        }
        $msg_str = implode("", $msg);

        #mail it to them
        mail( $posted_data['your-email'], 'Thanks for your enquiry', $msg_str );
    }

}
```

Note the **`$msg = array();`** as a string array, the **`$msg += "<multiline string>"`** for each case that matches a posted query variable, and the **`$msg_str = implode("", $msg)`** to make a final string (that may be HTML or non-html).

If you are using a **HTML email**, aligning the options' values right is a matter of **css rules**. So your final HTML email would look like:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .align-right
        {
            text-align: right;
            direction: rtl;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
...
...
...
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td class="option-name">California</td>
        <td class="option-value align-right">THE MULTILINE STRING</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="option-name">Texas</td>
        <td class="option-value align-right">THE MULTILINE STRING</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</html>
```