# Can I use below code (html, css) to make my website compatible with RTL?

Tags: html, css, arabic, right-to-left

I know that there is some standards from [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-dir). However this is just a thought.

Instead of using "dir" in html and body tag, can I use below custom attribute to identify layout?

**Actual**: `<html dir="rtl">`

**My**: `<html layout="rtl">`

After identifying Layout from above Tag, Is that suggested to use below line of code in css?

**Code**:

```
html[layout="rtl"] .heading-main , .title, .content {
  direction: rtl !important;
  text-align: right !important;
}
```

So that, I can add desired css code to selected elements to make my react App compatible with Arabic language.

Comment: Any particular reason for using `!important` in your css?

Comment: Nothing specific. Just to over write.
We can ignore as well if not required.

Comment: i know its not a part of your question, but dont use `!important` if not absolutely neccessary (e.g. overwriting inline styles from javascripts you cant change). Its evil.

Comment: @FabianSchöner Alright. Noted. Thank you.

Comment: @KrupalPatel I still don't get what wrong if you use `<html dir="rtl">` with `html[dir="rtl"]...` . Many project using this convention.

Comment: Because I don't want to change entire Layout. Even its RTL, I still need LTR for specific element/section.

Comment: @user.dz I think you are right. I can even over write for RTL as well using standard way so why to customize. It's working for me. 
Thanks for your direction.

Comment: @KrupalPatel would you share your final solution as answer here. Seems to me  worth sharing.